# promise async data extract issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

```
loadcsv(file: File): string[] {
  let csvRecordsArray: string[];
  this.parse(file).then((p) => {
    console.log(p);
    csvRecordsArray = p as string[];
  });
  console.log('mydata', csvRecordsArray);
  return csvRecordsArray;
}
```

`console.log` inside the `then` prints the data I need. Nothing wrong with the `Promise`. However, since it does not block my second `console.log` has undefined in `csvRecordsArray`. So I read up on `Promise`s and learnt that I need to `await`.  As soon as I type `async` to make `loadcsv` `async` ts lint says:

> Type 'string[]' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.

Please help me get out of this tailspin.

Comment: You cannot make a function that calls an asynchronous function and returns the result from the future immediately. You need to return a promise for the string array.

Comment: Everyone who voted duplicate didn't read the question. @Bergi you're too quick on the draw.

Comment: @Evert You mean this question is only about the type error (from code that wasn't even shown)? I think the OPs problem is his misunderstanding of async code, surfaced in the attempt to assign `csvRecordsArray = p` in the callback. (And yes, it was only me who voted duplicate, that comes from my shiny polished mjölnir :P)

Comment: @Bergi you should err on the side of caution. You obviously have been super helpful in the community, but quickly closing questions without explanation is what gives SO a bad name for newcomers.

Comment: @Evert I even commented. What explanation do you think is missing? Btw, if you like I can reopen the question

Comment: @Bergi I think OP has their answer, so no need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function is an `async` function because you need to use `await`, those functions always return a Promise.

So the correct signature for this is:

```
loadcsv(file: File): Promise<string[]>  {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the implementation of your `loadcsv` function by making it `async`. For that, you'll have to `await` the function call to `this.parse`.

Also since `async` functions are expected to return a `Promise`, you'll have to change the return type of your function to `Promise<string[]>`

Change your implementation like this:

```
async loadcsv(file: File): Promise<string[]> {
  let csvRecordsArray: string[];
  csvRecordsArray = await this.parse(file);
  console.log('mydata', csvRecordsArray);
  return csvRecordsArray as string[];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for both your responses. Appreciate it.